# Removing slimscroll from div

Tags: jquery, scroll, slimscroll

I got a div, and to make it fancier I use the [SlimScroll jQuery plugin](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) on that div

```
$('#scrollable').slimscroll({
   color: '#900',
   size: '8px',
   width: '300px',
   height: '500px'
});
```

now there's a moment when I want this div not to have this property anymore (but to have the browser default scrollbar). How can I remove the `slimscroll`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made this function which works great in my case

```
function destroySlimscroll(objectId) { 
   $("#"+objectId).parent().replaceWith($("#"+objectId)); 
}
```

Comment: could you do this in Fidle ??

Comment: Ok, give me some time!

Comment: This will leak memory, because the event subscriptions aren't disposed

Answer (score 18):

```
$("#scrollable").slimScroll({destroy: true});
```

Comment: Was it always there or they added this function in a recent update?

Comment: Can't be sure, but I think it was added after your question. It works for version 2 and newer.

Comment: version 2 of jquery or the plugin?

Comment: The SlimScroll plugin's version.

Comment: This will leak memory, because the event subscriptions aren't disposed

Comment: @ink The plugin's version is still only 1.3.8 five years later, I'm not sure how you have version 2?

Answer (score 6):

I did this and it works better than any other solution I saw..

```
$(".slimScrollBar,.slimScrollRail").remove();
$(".slimScrollDiv").contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `destroy` method on it, hopefully it supports.

```
$('#scrollable').slimscroll("destroy");
```

You can also remove all inline styles applied by the plugin

```
$('#scrollable').attr('style', '');
```

Comment: unfortunately the only thing it does is destroying my settings and set the default ones...

Comment: ok I'm noticing that the plugin creates a wraps $('#scrollable') with a div and it styles it.
So I have to remove that wrapper (which it just has a class) but keep my $('#scrollable') which is in it...

Comment: I made this function which works great in my case
`function destroySlimscroll(objectId)
{
 $("#"+objectId).parent().replaceWith($("#"+objectId));
}`

Comment: Thank you... I forgot to answer myself.
Vote up when I do, please =D

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble doing this in a large SPA app. scroll's just kept piling up on top of each other, even with calling the destroy method of slimScroll.

So here's my solution.

```
$('.slimScrollBar,.slimScrollRail').remove();
$('.slimScrollDiv').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).children());
})
```

This code runs and destroys all scrolls, then the controllers are free to bind scrolls as needed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me so I thought I would share my solution.

I load a function called `handleScroller()` on `document.ready()`.  When I perform an update on the `ul li` I call the `handleScroller()`  function again in order for the slimScrollDiv to become destroyed and rebuilt again. I set the height of the ul container also. It seems to be working quite well. Here is a sample of my code:

**CSS in style.css**
.scroller{height: 182px;}

**HTML/Bootsrap menu**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
   <!-- slimScroll notifications -->
   <li id="header_notification_bar"  class="hidden dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
    <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge">
            6
        </span>
   </a>
   <ul id="notifications" class="dropdown-menu extended"></ul>
   </li>
<!--other menu items ... //-->
</ul>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   handleScroller();
   VisitedHandler(); 
});

function VisitedHandler(){
   $("#notifs li").on("click",function(){

      $("#notifications").html('');     
      $('ul#notifs').html('');
      $("#notifications").append('<li><ul id="notifs" class="dropdown-menu-list scroller"></li>');
       var ul = $('#notifs');
           ul.append('<li id="general">New Announcement</li>')   
           ul.append('<li id="enhancements">New Page Enhancements</li>'); 

    handleScroller();

});
}

function handleScroller(){
  $("#notifs").slimscroll({destroy:true});
     var notes = $("#notifs");
     var height = notes.css("height");
     if($('#notifs .nws').size() < 5 && $('#notifs .nws').size() != 0)
        height = $('#notifs .nws').size() * 40 + 22;
     else      
        height = 182;
     //no Notifications
     if($('#notifs .nws').size() == 0)
        height = 0;
   $("#notifs").slimScroll({
    size: '10px',
    color: '#a1b2bd',
    railColor:'#272727',
    position: 'right',
    height: height,
    alwaysVisible: true,
    railVisible: true,
    disableFadeOut: true
   });
}
```

**NOTE:** There is a solution [here](http://bitishunter.vn/assets/plugins/node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/examples/dynamic-content.html) that wraps the `handleScroller()` logic around a `setInterval()`. I suggest staying away `setInterval()` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To enable slimscroll and disable slimscroll
$('#scrollable').slimscroll("destroy");